# How to disable panorama default animation

Tags: windows-phone

When we navigate to a page that has a panorama control. It shows a slide animation from right to left. How do we disable this default animation of panorama ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't. Unless you want to rewrite the [PanningLayer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.primitives.panninglayer%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) control from scratch. And really, why would you want to do that? It's against the default platform UX.

Comment: If I open a panorama page and if I navigate to the 2nd item in the panorama and press the start button, the app is deactivated. When it is activated again by pressing the hardware back button, in the panorama, the last viewed item has to be focused, that is 2nd item (in order to achieve tombstoning). I have done this. But when the app is activated, the first item comes visible first after that the animation happens then only the 2nd item comes to focus. It does not look good. Thats why I asked whether we can disable this animation.In this case also should we not disable the default animation ?

Comment: Actually the default behaviour for that seems to be to change the order of the items, so the last selected item appears first. (See the Music Hub).

Comment: Boo!  It depends on the application.  If you have an awesome loading screen, then you transition to show a pano its totally legit to not want a turnstile animation but a fade in.  See the fox news app

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't look like there is a good way of doing it.  Here is how I worked around it though.  Basically set the opacity to 0 until the animation is complete while you have the pano background & title showing behind the actual pano.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">

    <Image Source="{Binding BackgroundUri"></Image>
    <Image Source="{Binding Title}"></Image>


    <controls:Panorama x:Name="Panorama" ... />

    <Grid.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Grid.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard >
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="Panorama">
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.5" Value="0"/>
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.5" Value="1"/>
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Grid.Triggers>
</Grid>
```