# Panorama slides when app is launched

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml

In my WP7 application I am using a Panorama control which has four items.On app launching the last item of the Panorama show for a second then immediately slides to first item. I want to avoid this sliding effect. I didn't want to show the last item first for a second and the sliding effect.How can this possible? Please help me.

XAML code :

```
  <controls:Panorama x:Name="mainPano"  >

            <controls:Panorama.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Resources/Images/PanoBackground.png"/>
            </controls:Panorama.Background>



            <controls:PanoramaItem X:Name="Item1" Header="latest pix" Height="520" Tag="latest" Margin="0,-40,0,0"  Orientation="Horizontal" MaxWidth="460">
                ..........
            </controls:PanoramaItem >

            <controls:PanoramaItem X:Name="Item2" Header="explore pix" Height="520" Tag="explore" Style="{StaticResource MainPanoramaHeaderStyle}" Margin="0,-40,0,0" >
               .........
            </controls:PanoramaItem >

            <controls:PanoramaItem X:Name="Item3" Header="bookmarks" Height="520" Tag="bookmarks" Style="{StaticResource MainPanoramaHeaderStyle}" Margin="0,-40,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal" MaxWidth="460">
               .........
            </controls:PanoramaItem >

            <controls:PanoramaItem X:Name="Item4" Header="activity" Height="520" Tag="activity" Style="{StaticResource MainPanoramaHeaderStyle}" Margin="0,-40,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal" MaxWidth="460" >
                .............
            </controls:PanoramaItem >              

        </controls:Panorama>
```

Comment: Can you post your xaml for the offending page.

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6810176/how-to-disable-panorama-default-animation